# Swift Singleton Memory Leak

Tags: singleton

I'm using a singleton as a  container for localization strings, dictionary keys, and notification names used throughout the app.  It is initialized as follows:

```
class ConstantsManager {

     private init() {}

     class var sharedInstance: ConstantsManager {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: ConstantsManager! = ConstantsManager()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

     let localization = "NSLocalizedString(etc.)"
     let dictKey = "aKey"
     let notificationName = Notification.Name("name")
}
```

The first use of the singleton occurs in AppDelegate's application(_ application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).  When Instruments / Leaks reaches

> let manager = ConstantsManager.sharedInstance

a leak is indicated.  Does the call tree below indicate that initialization is occurring twice?  I'm wondering if the properties associated with a second initialization represent the leak.  Strangely, the leak doesn't occur on the simulator.  (I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 and OS X 10.12.3 for iOS 10.2 deployment.)

```
 Bytes Used           # Leaks     Symbol Name
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          ConstantsManager.init() -> ConstantsManager
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          ConstantsManager.__allocating_init() -> ConstantsManager
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          globalinit_33_8D935C4E2193156DAA2AB3DF99F55E80_func0
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          static ConstantsManager.(sharedInstance.getter).(Static #1).instance.unsafeMutableAddressor
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          static ConstantsManager.sharedInstance.getter
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          AppDelegate.registerUserDefaults() -> ()
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool
448 Bytes  100.0%     14          main
```